# nothing shows up in Java's paintComponent. How do I fix this?

Tags: java, user-interface, graphics, paint, paintcomponent

In Java, I need to draw a simple line with the paintComponent. Here is my attempt, but nothing was shown when I executed the program. Please show me the correct way of doing this.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class DrawLine extends JPanel {

    public Illusion(Color backColor){
        setBackground(backColor);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawLine(100, 100, 300, 100);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your painting a black line on a black background, so I'd say its working just fine. Try changing the color of the line

```
    g.setColor(Color.Red);
    g.drawLine(100, 100, 300, 100);
```

Your also not taking into account the actual size of the panel, I'd do something more along the lines of

```
    g.drawLine(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
```

As a test

You might like to have a read through

- [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)
- [Graphics2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Comment: Thank you for the help, I found a new tutorial that did a better job explaining things than the old one I used. Much Appreciated.

Comment: Check out the links I added, they should help